# Android onPause: Why stop Threads at all?

Tags: android, multithreading, actor

The background work in my Android-application is done by communicating sequential processes, meaning threads that listen for commands on a `BlockingQueue`.

The threads/actors are initialized in the `MainApplication`.

Stopping these threads during an `Activity.onPause` brings some complication, for example some commands on the `BlockingQueue` can arrive *before* `onResume` is called.

**Question 1**: Why bother stopping these threads during `onPause` at all? They are in a blocked state, not doing any work, so they should not have any performance impact.

**Question 2**: When `onPause` and then `onDestroy` is called, what is happening to these threads? Will the ART kill them? `.interrupt()` them? Is there some time-out?

Comment: *not doing any work* aren't they checking if there is any work to do?

Comment: The threads are in Waiting State.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your question is opinion based, but not stopping them does probably cost some performance. As a general rule of thumb you should stop all work when the user-interface is not shown to the user (after onStop). So it's up to you if keeping them in a waiting state is good enough.
2. `onDestory` only "destroys" your `Activity` instance not your VM instance (or process). Other singleton objects or objects not garbage collected will stay alive including background threads.

Comment: It doesn't destroy my MainApplication, or does it? The threads are started from there.

Comment: Nope is doesn't. But you must understand that as soon as your app doesn't have any active components (Activity, BroadcastReceiver, Service etc.) anymore Android may kill your app/process completely without any warning to clean up RAM memory so other apps can use it. So in extreme cases (low memory devices) your threads might be stopped eventually.